# For loop based on a float matrix in a bash script (Linux/Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, ubuntu

I am currently trying to run a FOR loop based on a float matrix in a bash script. The script works well if the matrix (i.e.arrayName) only consist of integer values, however fails completely for float values (as listed in the code below).
I know that bash scripts don't particularly deal well with floats, and require `| bc` to register floats. Does anyone know how to put this in proper syntax  so Ubuntu will read the float values in the matrix?

```
#!/bin/bash

arrayName=(0.373400000000000    14.5667000000000    16.3333000000000    2.32480000000000)

for i in ${arrayName[@]}
do
    gmx trjconv -s nvt_20ns.tpr -f nvt_20ns.trr -n 2Y3J_solv.ndx -o nvt_20ns_$(echo $i| bc).trr  -pbc mol -center -b $i -e $i  <<EOF
1 0 
EOF
done
```

Comment: You only need to use `bc` if you're performing arithmetic on the numbers. If you're just inserting them into the command uninterpreted, it doesn't matter that they're floating point.

Comment: For starters, you need to quote your variables: `"${arrayName[@]}"`.

Comment: Always run your script through shellcheck and fix the issues it finds as a first step.

Comment: Does `gmx trjconv` allow float values for `-b` and `-e` _time_?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm fairly new to bash script. I amended the following as suggested: ' "${arrayName[@]}" ' Checked script through shellcheck And it works now, thanks :)